# Style not applying to imported component from component library

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, vue.js, vite

I am building a library component that will be loaded into a different project. When I load the component into the other project no styling is being applied.

The component library uses vue 3, vite, scss & typescript.
For the component I have a separate scss file that I import in the component's style tag, which it's lang="scss".

This is the vite.config that I run for building the library:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue()
  ],
  base: '',
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: 'src/index.ts',
      name: 'ComponentLibrary',
      fileName: (format) => `component-library.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["vue"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: "Vue"
        }
      }
    },

    outDir: './vue-component-dist'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

in `'src/index.ts'` I register the component like this:

```
export {default as MyComponent} from "@/MyComponent.vue"
```

When I run the vite config to build the library it compiles all the scss into one css file.
I then pack the dist folder using `npm pack`, in the `package.json` I have the following:

```json
"type": "module",
  "main": "./vue-component-dist/component-library.umd.js",
  "module": "./vue-component-dist/component-library.es.js",
  "files": [
    "vue-component-dist"
  ],
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./vue-component-dist/component-library.es.js",
      "require": "./vue-component-dist/component-library.umd.cjs"
    },
    "./style.css": "./vue-component-dist/style.css"
  },
```

(note this is not the entire `package.json`, but the rest is irrelevant).

After that I import the tarball into my other project with `npm`, and import the component into vue:

```js
<script>
import {MyComponent} from '@ComponentLibrary/component-library'
export default {
  components: {
    MyComponent
  }
}
</script>
```

Using the component works perfectly, but it has no styling at all. It seems like I am building the library wrong so it doesn't use the style that is build with it. I can import the `style.css` from the package but I'd rather not.

Why won't the component use the style it was build with?

Thanks in advance.